# A word that means how authentic or true a replica is to the original

Tags: word-choice

I have been trying to recall a particular word for a week now.  The word is a property of a replica indicating the degree with which it was able to be true to the original.

Similar words are authentic, representative, etc.

Maybe something similar to integrity.  I feel like it is commonly used in this context, but in general it is not frequently used.

I would love to hear suggestions!

Comment: I'm sorry, but Writers.SE does not accept phrase requests (e.g. "What's a word/phrase that means...").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word I use for that:  fidelity.

Comment: "Fidelity" is the first word that came to my mind, too. Another possibility is "authenticity", though that means more "is it real or not" rather than "how much does it look like the real". Another is "accuracy", as in "this is a highly-accurate scale model".

Answer (score 1):

How about: verisimilitude? ...